Husqvarna 128ld Keeps stalling
Friend gave me his Weed whacker to fix, says it keeps stalling. I’ve cleaned the carburetor like four times now I believe, the fuel and return lines are clean and I’ve tried a new carburetor, yet the issue doesn’t go away.
I’m at a loss can someone tell me what I’m missing

https://www.husqvarna.com/us/support/128ld/,
https://www.manua.ls/husqvarna/128ld/manual
Are you aware 2-stroke engines use crankcase pressure and vacuum to operate the diaphragm type carb? Is the pressure/vacuum port in the crankcase blocked after removing the carb? Is the gasket blocking the port? Can you test for spark with plug removed, plug wire connected to it and plug grounded to crankcase as you pull on the starter rope? Is there compression?

@FDryer It dies as soon as I un choke it

Diagnosing and troubleshooting 2-stroke engines can be either easy or difficult since it relies on an individual to understand how 2-stroke engines operate without valves and supply crankcase pressure and vacuum to operate the carburetor. If the choke feeds a richer fuel mixture, this may be either a blocked small passageway between crankcase and carb or lower/lost compression. If choking allows the engine to run, then the ignition system is fine and the problem is fuel related.
